# Language used in Escrava Isaura opening theme

Tags: african-languages

The theme can be heard here at youtube http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=T6tWC-SnC2U

The music and "lere-lere" in the beginning come from Retirantes song, but the words starting from 0:08 *ARE NOT*. What language is this? It's not Portugal. Someone transcribed the passage like this

```
Ungazun garunge ungazun garunge, 
ungazun garunge ungazun garunge. 
Zambele garunge ungazun garunge, 
zambele garunge ungazun garunge
```

It's obviously very rough and not correct/misheard. The soap opera in question is about sugar cane plantation and black slaves in Brazil, so it's possible that the words have something to do with that.

Comment: "Propessor"? What language is *that*?

Comment: It's intentionally mispronounced Russian for childhood bullying purposes.

Comment: Sounds more like [zampele].

Comment: I have raised a question on Meta about whether this is on-topic: http://meta.linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/465/should-the-questions-of-identifying-language-be-on-topic

Comment: Oh year.I adore this soap opera and musical theme.

Comment: "It's not Portugal." The language is called Portuguese, not Portugal.

Answer (score 1):

The song appears in 2 versions, one in Portuguese, and the other in the unknown language. The Portuguese lyrics are (omitting repeated lines):

> Lerê, lerê, lerê, lerê, lerê
>
> Vida de negro é difícil, é difícil como o quê
>   Eu quero morrer de noite, na tocaia me matar
>   Eu quero morrer de açoite se tu, negra, me deixar
>
> Vida de negro é difícil, é difícil como o quê
>   Meu amor, eu vou-me embora, nessa terra vou morrer
>   Um dia não vou mais ver, nunca mais eu vou te ver

It's a reasonable assumption that the unknown-language lyrics are a translation.

---

[This guy claims it's Yoruba](http://www.tvrlive.com/abertura-novela-escrava-isaura/):

> Lere Lere, Lere-Lere-Lere
>   Lere Lere, Lere-Lere-Lere
>   Unga zunga unguê
>   Unga zunga unguê (bis)
>
> Tanguelê za unguê
>   Unga zunga unguê
>   Tanguelê za unguê
>   Unga zunga unguê
>
> Nagô nation, of people? from Benin to southwest of Nigeria, who spoke Yoruba. Brazilian traficants trade offering tobacco, powder, rifles in change of … people … prisioners of african tribal wars.

In [one old Yoruba dictionary](http://books.google.com/books/about/A_Dictionary_of_the_Yoruba_Language.html?id=UuUNAAAAYAAJ), I do find some near-matches:

- tangala - a bird
- tankalẹ: to spread about, communicate, publish
- lera (v., adj.) (be) strong, healthy

---

[Another guy gives a purported translation](http://www.kirishi.ru/?myforum_themeread_4488), without identifying the language:

```
Lere Lere, Lere-Lere-Lere        (Режем, режем, резь-резь-резь),
Lere Lere, Lere-Lere-Lere        (Режем, режем, резь-резь-резь),
Unga zunga ungue                 (Высокий сладкий тростник)
Unga zunga unga e                (Ой, высокий сладкий тростник)
Tanguele za ungue                     (Гля, какой высокий)
Unga zunga                           (Высокий и сладкий)
          Zunga e                                  (Ой, сладкий!)
```

The Russian text is a song about cutting reeds. It seems to have nothing to do with the Yoruba words or the Portuguese lyrics.

Comment: I know these versions. The Portuguese lyrics is from "Retirantes" song I mentioned. If you listen to it you will find that theme is not "Retirantes" or its translation. Parts of "Retirantes" were cut and pasted and mixed with "ungazunga" song. "Lere Lere" is from "Retirantes" back vocals and "ungazunga" is different thing so texts mentioning them together don't look trustworthy to me. Moreover "Tanguelê za unguê" is just short of syllables, it misses the second "ungazun garunge" part. I can try to rule out few languages spoken in Nigeria - Yoruba, Igala, Igbo and Hausa should need arise.

Answer (score 1):

I'm Brazilian (so, I speak Portugese). I have researched about this lyrics, so I think the first part may be in Zulu. Even though I'm not sure about it, the lyrics' translation could be something like this:

(Zulu)

Lare, Lare! Lare, lare, lare! (Distress, distress! Distress, distress, distress!) ... (repeat)

Unga zu ngaru nge? Unga zu ngaru nge? (Cold you send this as a priority? Cold you send this as a priority?) ... (repeat)

Zambele, ngaru nge. Unga zu ngaru nge? (By mercy, you send this. Cold you send this as a priority?) ... (repeat)

(Portuguese)

Vida de negro é difícil (The life of a black is so difficult)

É difícil como o quê (It is so difficult as a thing) ... (repeat)

Eu quero morrer de noite (I want to die at night)

Na tocaia me matar (In the ambush I want to kill myself)

Eu quero morrer de açoite (I want to die so whipped)

Se tu, negra, me deixar (If you, black woman, leave me)

Vida de negro é difícil (The life of a black is so difficult)

É difícil como o quê (It is so difficult as a thing) ... (repeat)

Meu amor, eu vou-me embora (My love, I am going to go away)

Nessa terra vou morrer (On this land I will go to die)

Um dia não vou mais ver (Someday I will not see)

Nunca mais eu vou te ver (Never again I will see you)

Vida de negro é difícil (The life of a black is so difficult)

É difícil como o quê (It is so difficult as a thing) ... (repeat)

*(you can hear both parts on https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XecW-4v-5zo)*